# Restricting file types in JQuery File upload demo

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, file-upload, blueimp

I am using [JQuery file upload demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) for my next project with Codeigniter. Can anyone tell me how do I achieve the following :

- Restricting upload file types to .zip and .rar
- Restricting file size
- Clearing the list of Uploaded files (JQuery file upload plugin displays the list of already uploaded files)

Help appreciated !!

Comment: Make sure you also do all of these restrictions/validations on the server-side.

Answer (score 70):

you probably have a plethora of solutions now, however I wanted to use the BASIC plugin for the jquery uploader, i.e. without any other scripts.. for some reason the maxFileSize/fileTypes options were not working - however that is mostly no doubt to my lack of reading the documentation!

Anyway for me, it was as quick as doing the following:

```
    add: function (e, data) {
        var goUpload = true;
        var uploadFile = data.files[0];
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
            common.notifyError('You must select an image file only');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
            common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (goUpload == true) {
            data.submit();
        }
    },
```

So just using the ADD option to only allow the image types in the regex, and checking (in my case) the file size is a max of 2mb.

Rather basic, and again I am sure the maxFileSize options work, just I am only including the basic plugin script jquery.fileupload.js

**EDIT**
I should have added in my case I am uploading just one file (a profile image) so hence the data.files[0].. you could iterate through the files collection of course.

Comment: Finally! I've been looking a lot for an example that worked. Thx :)

Comment: `add` is run per file. Therefore `data.submit` is only referring to one file.

Comment: Wouldn't be happier if I don't get this..:)

Comment: very helpful .. thz

Comment: Great, I just added alert("You must select an image file only") before 
common.notifyError('You must select an image file only') to notify the user

Answer (score 7):

In jquery.fileupload-ui.js edit this part:

```
   $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {
        // The maximum allowed file size:
        maxFileSize: 100000000,
        // The minimum allowed file size:
        minFileSize: undefined,
        // The regular expression for allowed file types, matches
        // against either file type or file name:
        acceptFileTypes:  /(zip)|(rar)$/i,
        ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

To clear the list of uploaded files - Remove the $.getJSON call from main.js if you don't need that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation;

```
$('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX({
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // Maximum File Size in Bytes - 5 MB
    minFileSize: 100000, // Minimum File Size in Bytes - 100 KB
    acceptFileTypes: /(zip)|(rar)$/i  // Allowed File Types
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One other way to do is as follows.

```
 $('#upload').fileupload({ 
       change: function (e, data) { 
                if (!(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|pdf)$/i).test(data.files[0].name)) {
                    alert('Not Allowed');
                    return false;
                }
        } 
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

try looking at this line :

```
 process: [
            /*
                {
                    action: 'load',
                    fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                    maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
                },
                {
                    action: 'resize',
                    maxWidth: 1920,
                    maxHeight: 1200,
                    minWidth: 800,
                    minHeight: 600
                },
```

in jquery.fileupload-fp.js